# push element to 2D array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

```
$peter=array('cs204'=>array(10,10,10));
$peter=array('cs366'=>array(7,8,9));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($peter);
echo '</pre>';
```

I am trying to insert values into an array $peter with course number(cs204,cs366) as keys. Instead of adding to second element to the array it is rewriting the data.
This is the current output(Actual):

```
Array
(
    [cs366] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 9
        )

)
```

But I need this one as output(Expected):

```
Array
(
    [cs204] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 10
        )

    [cs366] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 9
        )

)
```

Please help me. I want to insert second element as: `$peter=array('cs366'=>array(7,8,9));` 
but not like this: `$peter['cs366']=array(7,8,9);`

Comment: How are you getting these arrays? Also, why this `$peter['cs366']=array(7,8,9);` is not suitable for your purpose?

Comment: How am I getting these arrays?
I didn't quite get you.

Comment: I mean, from where you getting these arrays i.e. `array('cs204'=>array(10,10,10))` and `array('cs366'=>array(7,8,9))`? Without any proper explanation, it will be all guesswork.

Comment: I have initialized an array named $peter with index(key) cs204 and value array(10,10,10). And now I am trying to push another element to the array with key cs366 and value array(7,8,9)

Comment: So `$peter['cs366']=array(7,8,9);` suits well with your code, isn't it? Why you don't want to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$peter=array('cs204'=>array(10,10,10));
$peter=array_merge($peter, array('cs366'=>array(7,8,9)));
```

Comment: While this would do it, it's over-thought / engineered when you can just have `$peter['cs366'] = ...`.

Comment: Depends on context, if you absolutely know the key will be cs366 sure, but if not, you would be in trouble. Besides, I don't think merging two arrays with array_merge is over-thought at all, quite the contrary :-)

Comment: @oli Thank you. you gave me a satisfactory answer.

If you don't mind, could you please tell me why its not working with $peter=array_push($peter, array('cs366'=>array(7,8,9)));
?

Comment: just remove $peter=, as array_push will add to $peter

Answer (score 0):

Think this is what your going for:

```
$peter = array();
$peter['cs204']=array(10,10,10);
$peter['cs366']=array(7,8,9);
```

Comment: Nope, consider what that would give an compare to what op is after.

Comment: That would give an array index staring from 0, which is a three dimensional array.

Comment: I edited it. if this is not what your looking for ill just delete my awnser.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $peter['cs204']=array(10,10,10);
 $peter['cs366']=array(7,8,9);

 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($peter);
 echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not just declaring both sub-arrays at the same time?

```
$peter = array('cs204' => array(10, 10, 10), 'cs366' => array(7, 8, 9));
```

Or if you prefer multi-line:

```
$peter = array(
    'cs204' => array(10, 10, 10),
    'cs366' => array(7, 8, 9)
);
```

If you **must** achieve the result in two statements:

```
$peter = array('cs204' => array(10, 10, 10));
$peter['cs366'] => array(7, 8, 9);
```